# Floating elements, full width

Tags: css, css-float

I have a fixed size layout where I center the content container.

I want the menu (home, about, contact, login), to span 100% of the screen.

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxhc5/1/

[image]

The result I want is this: 
[image]

I have tried a to make a 100% width container with the menus, where I would have a container inside to center the menu, but it did not work well, because then the layout is relative, changed with the window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap an extra div arround the menu, give it the grey background, remove the extra padding, make the menu bg white:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Hxhc5/3/

This is problematic when we want to keep the space between the menu and the right col 'open' though.

The easiest way and probably the best is to have a mock image of which the middle is left 'open' and use it as a background. Since a png image of this type is insanely small it is better than more markup, css or a js solution, plus it has no quirks if used correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Hxhc5/10/

You also showed your actual developement site; if you want to implement this for the menu you will have to make the menu fixed height (everthing else and its width can still be fluid) due to the type of opacity you use in the layer. The same background trick can be made to work with it.

Comment: What if the background is not just white? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxhc5/5/ ?

Comment: @Ragnar123 that certainly complicates things, would've been nice to know about from the beginning ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry. My immediate guess was that it did not matter.

Comment: Its not impossible though, let me mock something up.

Comment: @Ragnar123 actually the absolute simpelest method to do this with the least overhead is making a png backgound image that is wide enough to span the entire width, and center it as a background and leave a gap in the middle where the content sits. Other options would be more or less rebuilding the html/css structure which take a bit too much of my time or a very ugly JS method to keep the boxes sized correctly. So take your pick. The HTML method would be slightly experimental so I can't give you good pointers for that, but I'd need a  lot more html & css to do it.

Comment: @Ragnar123 that would be to create the image, it would be the least amount of overhead since a png of this type should be bytes at most... remove the white color from `#menu` and replace the `background: #aaa` with an url to the image and repeat-y so it is stretched out over the div...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a background image that spans the entire page instead?

Comment: I already use a background image for my site, and I do not find it suitable to use a background where I absolutely lock this element in height.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the content of the menu into another div, with `width: 500px, margin: auto;` and set the menu width to 100%. Here is updated jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Hxhc5/2/

Comment: How about the space in between the menus? possible to keep a white background there=

Comment: @gabitzish the width 100% is not needed, automatic sizing will take care of that and is much cleaner.

Comment: What if the background is not as simple as a color: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxhc5/5/ ?

Comment: @sg3s you are right, it works without setting menu width to 100%.

Comment: @gabitzish its slightly bugged in that if you resize the frame fast enough the grey jumps to the next line and the grey box misses one pixel in height. Less overhead would be using an image.

Comment: Works fine to me at resize. About that pixel missing, I'm on firefox/ubuntu, looks ok to me, but there might be some differences between browsers and it can be calculated. You would have the same problem with the image height.